# Break Columns to second Page in report

Tags: ms-access

i am having a Problem with my Report.
As you can see in the picture below, my current Report has a Column for each employee.
Now that we are > 10 Employees, i need to break some of the columns to a second page.
Is there a possibility to achiev that?

It is long times ago, since i used MS-ACCESS, so this could be only a few keywords that i Need

thanks in advance
[image: exampleImage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access, if a report is too wide for the width set in page settings, the rest of the columns should automatically print on another page.